# GORM: Find by collection contents

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I Have the following two classes:

```
class Person{

 String name

  static hasMany = [
     items: Item
 ]
}

class Item{
 String name
}
```

Multiple Persons can also have the same Item. I'm trying to get a list of all Persons that have a specific item in their collection. I.E. Both Person A and B have Item A in their list so return them both. Unfortunately their is no findAllByCollectionContains() the closest is is findAllByCollection() which requires an exact set.

I've been trying executeQuery to give me a but more control and haven't come up with anything yet.

Example of what I have tried:

```
 Person.executeQuery("select name from Person p where ? in p.items",[item])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the items collection, then you can query on it easily

```
 Person.executeQuery("select name from Person p join p.items as i where i = ?",[item])
```

Comment: That works great. but could you explain a bit more as to why it works? Thanks!

Comment: When you join `p.items` you now can query based off the individual item instead of the collection of items. Take a look at the HQL docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html